# How to search for questions with negative score?

Tags: support, search

I'm in the process of cleaning some junk out of our SE.

Is it possible to search for questions that have a negative score, i.e. to exclude search results that have a score of zero or greater?

The exclude `-score:0 -score:1` gets interpreted as search terms. Currently, I am limited to "sorting by score" and looking at the last pages.